# NSIS: How do I allow multiple user choice screens that select the sections to install?

Tags: nsis

I'm attempting to create an installer that asks the user a series of questions to decide which components to install. Each choice (potentially) influences the available options in later choices (else I would just do a normal components page—I don't want to give the user invalid options).

How do I accomplish such a thing? If I just use the components page, all the options are shown, some combinations of which are completely invalid. I don't want to let the user select those. *Is it possible to leave out the components page?*

Here's a minimal working example of what I'm trying. (Sorry it's long, I couldn't really simplify the dialog code.)

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include Sections.nsh
Name "mwe"
OutFile "mwe.exe"
InstallDir C:\mwe

Var hwnd
Var Level1Opt

Page custom SelectLevel1Opt ProcessLevel1

Function SelectLevel1Opt
   nsDialogs::Create 1018
   pop $hwnd

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Please select level 1 option"
   Pop $hwnd

   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 10% 12u 100% 12u "Level 1 A"
   Pop $hwnd
   nsDialogs::SetUserData $hwnd "Level 1 A"
   ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd SetLevel1

   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 10% 24u 100% 12u "Level 1 B"
   Pop $hwnd
   nsDialogs::SetUserData $hwnd "Level 1 B"
   ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd SetLevel1

   nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function SetLevel1
   Pop $hwnd
   nsDialogs::GetUserData $hwnd
   Pop $Level1Opt
   MessageBox MB_OK "Selected: $Level1Opt"
FunctionEnd

Function ProcessLevel1
   ${If} $Level1Opt == "Level 1 A"
      !insertmacro SelectSection Level1A
   ${ElseIf} $Level1Opt == "Level 1 B"
      !insertmacro SelectSection Level1B
   ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd


Page directory
Page instfiles

Section ""
  MessageBox MB_OK "Common Install"
SectionEnd

Section /o "" Level1A
  MessageBox MB_OK "Level 1 A"
SectionEnd

Section /o "" Level1B
  MessageBox MB_OK "Level 1 B"
SectionEnd
```

No matter what I choose, neither `Level1A` nor `Level1B` sections get run. The selection from the dialog is correctly detected in the handler and the post function. However, selecting the sections isn't causing them to run. Even if I add a components page, neither of them is selected.

I looked in `Selection.nsh`, and the example it refers to (one-section.nsi) doesn't really do what I want, because it uses the components page. (I also don't understand quite how it works.)

What am I doing wrong? In what way am I misunderstanding the way NSIS is supposed to work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `insertmacro SelectSection ${Level1A}`?

Comment: @idleberg I don't see any different behavior when I do that, except a warning message at compile-time: `unknown variable/constant "{Level1A}" detected, ignoring (macro:SelectSection:4)`

Comment: Does `$Level1Opt` have any value in ProcessLevel1? If not, get the state of your radio buttons in the leave function. PS: I'd test it myself, but I'm currently not on Windows.

Comment: I added a messagebox statement there, and it's got the value I'd expect: either `"Level 1 A"` or `"Level 1 B"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As idleberg says, the correct syntax is `!insertmacro SelectSection ${Level1A}` but you get a warning because the section id is not defined until after its `Section` instruction in your .nsi. You need to move the functions that use `${Level1A}` below the sections in your source code:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include Sections.nsh
Page custom SelectLevel1Opt ProcessLevel1
Page instfiles

Section ""
  MessageBox MB_OK "Common Install"
SectionEnd

Section /o "a" Level1A
  MessageBox MB_OK "Level 1 A"
SectionEnd

Section /o "b" Level1B
  MessageBox MB_OK "Level 1 B"
SectionEnd

Var hInnerDialog
Var hL1A
Var hL1B

Function SelectLevel1Opt
nsDialogs::Create 1018
pop $hInnerDialog
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Please select level 1 option"
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 10% 12u 100% 12u "Level 1 A"
Pop $hL1A
nsDialogs::SetUserData $hL1A ${Level1A} ; Only used by the generic function
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 10% 24u 100% 12u "Level 1 B"
Pop $hL1B
nsDialogs::SetUserData $hL1B ${Level1B} ; Only used by the generic function
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function ProcessLevel1
${NSD_GetState} $hL1A $1
${If} $1 <> ${BST_UNCHECKED}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${Level1A}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Level1B}
${Else}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${Level1B}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Level1A}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

The ProcessLevel1 function can also be implemented as a loop if there are many radio buttons:

```
Function ProcessLevel1
StrCpy $0 ""
loop:
    FindWindow $0 "${__NSD_RadioButton_CLASS}" "" $hInnerDialog $0 
    System::Call "USER32::GetWindowLong(p$0,i${GWL_STYLE})i.r1"
    IntOp $1 $1 & ${BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON}
    ${If} $1 = ${BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON} ; Is it a auto radio button?
        nsDialogs::GetUserData $0 ; Get the section id
        Pop $2
        ${NSD_GetState} $0 $1
        ${If} $1 <> ${BST_UNCHECKED}
            !insertmacro SelectSection $2
        ${Else}
            !insertmacro UnselectSection $2
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    IntCmp $0 0 "" loop loop
FunctionEnd
```